# pointer to one struct in another, writing and reading it from file gives SegFault

Tags: c, file, pointers, segmentation-fault, structure

I am brushing up my C skills from Learn C The Hard Way, currently I am at [17th Exercise](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex17.html).

I am doing the 'Extra Credits' part. Making the database code given on that page to get
I am trying to

"Change the code to accept parameters for MAX_DATA and MAX_ROWS, store them in the Database struct, and write that to the file, thus creating a database that can be arbitrarily sized"

So, I commented out the #define directives, and changed Address and Database structs as given:

```
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
};

struct Database {
    int MAX_DATA;
    int MAX_ROWS;
    struct Address *rows;
};
```

So that, I can get MAX_DATA, and MAX_ROWS parameters from the user to create a database as per his liking. Other things I changed in the code are --

The Database_create function :

```
void Database_create(struct Connection *conn, int MAX_DATA, int MAX_ROWS)
{
        int i = 0;
        conn->db->MAX_DATA = MAX_DATA;
        conn->db->MAX_ROWS = MAX_ROWS;
        conn->db->rows = malloc(sizeof(struct Address) * MAX_ROWS);
        for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
                struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};
                conn->db->rows[i] = addr;
        }
}
```

The part where I am getting 'Invalid read of 4 bytes', and SegFault is :

```
void Database_set(struct Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email)
{
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];
    int MAX_DATA = conn->db->MAX_DATA;
    if(addr->set) die("Already set, delete it first");
    /* This if statement gives error for addr->set */
    addr->set = 1;
    addr->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_DATA);
    addr->email = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_DATA);
    // WARNING: bug, read the "How To Break It" and fix this
    char *res = strncpy(addr->name, name, MAX_DATA);
    // demonstrate the strncpy bug
    if(!res) die("Name copy failed");

    res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
    if(!res) die("Email copy failed");
}
```

I know this code snippets isn't the whole part, but I can't paste the whole code here.
So, I've posted it here : http://pastebin.com/EbKShT3r
I can create and write database for the first run using 'c' option. However, to add entries using 's' option, the Segmentation Fault occurs.

**EDIT** :
So, Finally, I got this program working with the solution given under by @WhizCraig
However, for freeing the memory, here is what I am trying :

```
void Database_close(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int i;
    if (conn) {
        int MAX_ROWS = conn->db->MAX_ROWS;
        for (i=0; i<MAX_ROWS; i++) {
            struct Address *row = conn->db->rows+i;
            if (row->set) {
                free(row->name);
                free(row->email);
            }
        }
        free(conn->db->rows);
        if(conn->file) fclose(conn->file);
        if(conn->db) free(conn->db);
        free(conn);
    }
}
```

And, I am getting errors in Valgrind, memory *is* leaking. I don't understand the error in above code.
However, the main problem appears to be solved :)

Comment: check if `addr` can be `NULL` before your `if` in question.

Comment: Just for info, the `strncpy()` calls will NOT null-term your strings if the number of chars at the source pointer is greater than or equal to MAX_DATA. as your comment says, you need to fix that if you *ever* plan on using them for anything remotely related to a C-string operation. It is ***not*** a bug. It is documented that way. strncmp() *always* writes N chars, where N is the size limit. if youur source is shorter, it will tail-fill with 0's. if it is longer, it will cut off after the N'th char and will not place a 0.

Comment: Thanks @phoeagon for your response. I did add this line 
if(&addr->set == NULL) printf("Aaah\n");
before original if. And it passes through it without printing "Aaah\n".
And the problem persists.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I am aware of it. Thanks, btw.

Comment: @RohittShinde no. I mean, you add `assert(addr)` before the `if` in question. BTW you need to `#include <cassert>` whatsoever.

Comment: @phoeagon, still the problem persists. I've already allocated memory for it, so, I guess, that wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: why don't you run it on a debugger ?

Comment: @RohittShinde You mean it does die on evaluating `(addr->set)` but `addr` is a pointer to some allocated space?

Comment: @phoeagon Check the Database_load function from the code. That's where I am allocating memory for 'rows'

Comment: @phoeagon No. It doesn't die.

Comment: @CCoder I am using Valgrind.

Comment: Valgrind is not a debugger. Use gdb . It will point you to the instruction which is causing the fault. Also you can perform execution line by line.

Comment: @CCoder Okay, thanks. I will learn to use it.

Comment: @CCoder I got this from GDB :
<blink>
(gdb) run people s 1 rosh roshg
Starting program: /home/rohit/raw_code/lcthw/ex17 people s 1 rosh roshg
ex17: ex17.c:120: Database_set: Assertion `addr->set' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a51445 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64 ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
</blink>
I don't understand it, though. :/

Comment: @RohittShinde You're still using the provided db-write method, correct ? if so, it is not correct, and that needs to be fixed before you can attack this. According to your code on pastebin, you still are using it, so I can only assume you're still suffering from its problems.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, I am using the provided write method, but I don't understand the need of 'fixing' it. I just have to write the allocated memory, right? Can you explain it more?

Comment: @RohittShinde Why did you assert `addr->set`? shouldn't you be `assert`ing `addr`?

Comment: @RohittShinde typing it up right now.

Comment: @RohittShinde Hope you have compiled your program with -g option of gcc. Put a breakpoint at start of Database_set as 'b Database_set'and then use 'step' command of gdb to execute line by line. You can also check the values of variables using 'watch' command.

Comment: @CCoder Yes, I have compiled it with -g option. And I wonder, the program is working correctly in GDB. Says, process **** exited normally.
Maybe I need to know GDB more, it's still kinda confusing me.

Comment: @Rohit as you find a solution, it would probably be good that you put it in an answer which you accept then (you might need to wait 24h before you can accept it), so the question appears as "answered" and not "unanswered" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
};

struct Database {
    int MAX_DATA;
    int MAX_ROWS;
    Address **rows; // USE ARRAY OF POINTERS
};

void Database_create(Connection *conn, int MAX_DATA, int MAX_ROWS)
{
        int i = 0;
        conn->db->MAX_DATA = MAX_DATA;
        conn->db->MAX_ROWS = MAX_ROWS;
        conn->db->rows = (Address**)malloc(sizeof(Address*) * MAX_ROWS);

        for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
                conn->db->rows[i] = (Address*)malloc(sizeof(Address));
                conn->db->rows[i]->id = i;
                conn->db->rows[i]->set = 0;
        }
}

void Database_set(Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email)
{
    if (!(conn && conn->db && conn->db->rows && conn->db->rows[id])) return;

    Address *addr = conn->db->rows[id];
    int MAX_DATA = conn->db->MAX_DATA;

    if(addr->set == 0) die("Already set, delete it first");

    addr->set = 1;
    addr->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_DATA);
    addr->email = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_DATA);

    char *res = strncpy(addr->name, name, MAX_DATA);
    if(!res) die("Name copy failed");

    res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
    if(!res) die("Email copy failed");
}

void Database_close(Connection *conn)
{
        size_t i;
        if(conn) {
                if (con->db && conn->db->rows) {
                        for (i = 0; i < conn->db->MAX_ROWS; i++) {

                                Address *cur = conn->db->rows[i];
                                free(cur);

                        }
                }

                if(conn->file) fclose(conn->file);
                if(conn->db) free(conn->db);
                free(conn);
        }
}
```

Comment: Khaled, See the above edit. I've done few more changes with the old code, but still few bytes are leaking. However, I made _some_ changes according to your code, got few bugs, fixed them, but the main problem for which this thread was made, comes back again.

In Database_write function, where we write addr->name, and addr->email, SegFault occurs saying Trying to read uninitialized address.  So, again, I made changes, created an Address struct, initiated it, and assigned its address to conn->db->rows[i] in Database_create.

Here is the code : http://pastebin.com/i00VZ8JR
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I worked on the problem, and I've got it working now. 
Check this improved version : http://pastebin.com/MvLXkDCz
I've not checked other options, but, now I can create the database file, add entries, and list them all. However, the memory seems to be leaking only while 'listing' the entries. Have a look at it. :)

Comment: @Rohit Glad to hear it worked out, if you see that my solution helped solving your problem, you can choose it as an accepted solution

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code Rohit posted here: http://pastebin.com/MvLXkDCz to fix the memory leaks. It runs through Valgrind without any errors. The relevant modifications are posted below:

```
void Database_close(Connection *conn)                                                 
{                                                                                     
  size_t i;                                                                           
  if(conn) {                                                                          
    if(conn->db && conn->db->rows) {                                                  
      for(i = 0; i < conn->db->max_rows; i++) {                                       
        Address *cur = conn->db->rows[i];                                             
        free(cur->name);                                                              
        free(cur->email);                                                             
        free(cur);                                                                    
      }                                                                               
      free(conn->db->rows);                                                           
    }                                                                                 
    if(conn->file) fclose(conn->file);                                                
    if(conn->db) free(conn->db);                                                      
    free(conn);                                                                       
  }                                                                                   
}   

void Database_delete(Connection *conn, int id)                                        
{                                                                                     
  conn->db->rows[id]->set = 0;                                                        
}
```

You can find the complete program here:https://github.com/sookoor/Learn-C-the-Hard-Way/blob/master/ex17.c

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers

Comment: You should post the relevant modifications you made directly into your answer to make it self-contained.