# Segfault in checking c pointer (LCTHW - Ex17, Extra Credit)

Tags: c, valgrind

I am working on the extra credit for Exercise 17 of Learn C the Hard Way.

I am getting stuck in trying to figure out what Valgrind is complaining about.

I've done a lot of researching and found [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950241/pointer-to-one-struct-in-another-writing-and-reading-it-from-file-gives-segfaul) seems to be essentially the same issue, but the solution doesn't work for me. I've looked at a few other solutions on Github and Pastebin, but the code is so different that for someone just learning C I cannot figure it out.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Pertinent code:

```
void Database_set(struct Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email)
{
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];
    if (addr->set) die("Already set, delete it first", conn);

    addr->set = 1;

    const int MAX_DATA = conn->db->MAX_DATA;
    addr->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_DATA);
    addr->email = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_DATA);

    char *res = strncpy(addr->name, name, MAX_DATA);
    if (!res) die("Name copy failed", conn);
    res[conn->db->MAX_DATA - 1] = '\0';

    res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
    if (!res) die("Email copy failed", conn);
    res[conn->db->MAX_DATA - 1] = '\0';
}
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/FFwfMpz0) is my full raw source code.

Below is my valgrind errors.

```
$ valgrind  ./ex17 db.dat s 1 zed zed@zedshaw.com
==22971== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22971== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22971== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22971== Command: ./ex17 db.dat s 1 zed zed@zedshaw.com
==22971== 
==22971== Invalid read of size 4
==22971==    at 0x400D15: Database_set (ex17.c:133)
==22971==    by 0x40109C: main (ex17.c:208)
==22971==  Address 0x51f237c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22971== 
==22971== Invalid write of size 4
==22971==    at 0x400D31: Database_set (ex17.c:135)
==22971==    by 0x40109C: main (ex17.c:208)
==22971==  Address 0x51f237c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22971== 
==22971== Invalid write of size 1
==22971==    at 0x4C2C1B7: strncpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22971==    by 0x400DE1: Database_set (ex17.c:145)
==22971==    by 0x40109C: main (ex17.c:208)
==22971==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22971== 
==22971== 
==22971== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==22971==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==22971==    at 0x4C2C1B7: strncpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22971==    by 0x400DE1: Database_set (ex17.c:145)
==22971==    by 0x40109C: main (ex17.c:208)
==22971==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==22971==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==22971==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==22971==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==22971==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==22971== 
==22971== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22971==     in use at exit: 1,624 bytes in 5 blocks
==22971==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 0 frees, 1,624 bytes allocated
==22971== 
==22971== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22971==    definitely lost: 512 bytes in 1 blocks
==22971==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22971==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22971==    still reachable: 1,112 bytes in 4 blocks
==22971==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22971== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22971== 
==22971== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22971== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Run with gdb which shall tell you the problem.

Comment: Both your write and read/set functionality are horridly flawed. `struct Database` has a raw pointer `rows`. Writing that to disk and reloading it from file will *not* work, and invokes undefined behavior. You need to write your save/load features to properly save the *data*; not the raw pointers.

Answer (score -1):

I'd check what happens at lines 133, 135 and 145 in your code, which is where you are told the problem is. You cleverly didn't post any line numbers, but it's easy to figure out that reading and writing addr->set is causing a problem, which means that addr is rubbish.

Check what the value of id is. Check whether conn->db is set at all.

A bit of critique: Calling strncpy is DANGEROUS. Your instructor should NEVER allow you to use it. And it's completely unneeded because you can just allocate name and email in the right size. I have never, ever seen anyone checking the return value of strcpy or strncpy. If it fails, it crashes. Use variables consistently. Using MAX_DATA in one place and conn->db->MAX_DATA in another place opens the chances of bugs. Find meaningful variable names. MAX_DATA is meaningless.

Comment: I have checked at these lines and realize they are the problem (hence including them in the snippet above). "it's easy to figure out that reading and writing addr->set is causing a problem, which means that addr is rubbish" agree... but I am sorry that I do not understand why it is rubbish.